# Getting a value from a custom field from a page that shares a parent with the current page

Tags: php, custom-field, child-pages

I have a page that has a true/false custom field.

What I want to do is output a link on another page that shares a parent with the page with the custom field.

Below is code from Wordpress Reference that allows me to target the page that shares a parent.

```
<?php
if ( $post->post_parent ) {
$children = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
    'echo'     => 0
) );
} else {
$children = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => $post->ID,
    'echo'     => 0
) );
}

if ( $children ) : ?>

WANT TO INSERT LINK HERE

<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the code I am using to insert my link via an Advanced Custom Field checkbox.

```
<?php if ( get_field( 'show_video_menu' ) ): ?>

<li><a id="artists-video" href="/<?php global $post;
if($post->post_parent) { $post_data = get_post($post->post_parent);
echo $post_data->post_name; }?>/video">Video</a></li>

<?php endif; // end of if field_name logic ?>
```

I was close, but I cannot seem to combine the codes in a way the shows the link only on the page that shares the parent. The link was occurring on all pages using the same Page Template.

This is the code I am currently using

```
<?php
if ( $post->post_parent ) {
$children = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
    'echo'     => 0
) );
} 

if ( $children || get_field( 'show_video_menu' ) ): ?>

<li><a id="artists-video" href="/<?php global $post;
if($post->post_parent) { $post_data = get_post($post->post_parent);
echo $post_data->post_name; }?>/video">Video</a></li>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I have created a Video Page with the parent Margo Wolowiec with the Custom Field however it was showing on other unrelated pages as well.

Comment: you need to pass the post id of that page to get_field, wp_list_pages returns html, try this instead https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there are only two children in such cases.

```
<?php
$child_id = $post->ID;
if ( $post->post_parent ) {
    $args = array(
                    'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
                    'post_type'   => 'page', 
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_status' => 'publish' 
                  );
    $children = get_children($args);
    if(count($children) == 2) {
        $child_id = $children[0]->ID == $post->ID ? $children[1]->ID : $children[0]->ID;
    }
} 

if ( get_field( 'show_video_menu' , $child_id ) ): ?>

<li><a id="artists-video" href="/<?php global $post;
if($post->post_parent) { $post_data = get_post($post->post_parent);
echo $post_data->post_name; }?>/video">Video</a></li>

<?php endif; ?>
```